# 36 inch by 36 inch counter depth refrigrator

Tags: refrigerator, shopping

I wanna buy a fridge with 36 inch depth, 36 inch width and any height. The main feature I need is I want it to be flushed by the kitchen cabinets (like subzero). Is there any brand except wolf I could check?
Thanx

Comment: Please refer to our [equipment tag wiki](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/equipment/info) for an explanation of what types of equipment/appliance questions are on topic. Neither brand recommendations nor installation questions are considered culinary topics here.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the major manufactures make counter-depth models.  [Here is a selection of models sold by Best Buy](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/Refrigerators/Counter-Depth-Refrigerators/abcat0901003.c?id=abcat0901003) - GE, KitchenAid, Samsung, Frigidaire, Bosch, Electrolux, and Whirlpool are all represented.